# how to handle generic api errors in rails 5

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-5

I am writing an error handler for my application.
Here is the code

```
rescue_from InvalidArgumentError, with: :display_400_error
rescue_from UserAccessAuthorizationError, UsersController::UserProfileAuthorizationError, with: :display_403_error
rescue_from InvalidResourceError, ActionController::RoutingError, ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :display_404_error
rescue_from Exception, with: :display_500_error
```

So for known exceptions I have defined what to display but for unknown exceptions I want to display 500 error. I have added rescue_from Exception to handle unknown exceptions. but since its a parent class so now whatever exceptions is raised its displaying 500 error. Can anyone please tell me how to handle this. I am new to ruby on rails